# How to convert a datetime string to UTC string?

Tags: php, datetime, utc, dst

I have a datetime string like this:

```
`2012-09-03 22:00 Central USA Time`.
```

and i want to convert it to the UTC time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gmdate()` and `strtotime()` :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('2012-09-03 22:00'));
```

Instead of `Central USA Time`, use the supported timezones : http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

The `date_default_timezone_get()` function will always give you the right timezone

Comment: But you didnt pass the original timezone ?!?!

Comment: Right, I'll edit my post, but you shouldn't use `Central USA Time` anymore

Comment: Same thing : `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); $localTime = date('Y-m-d H:i', $utctime);`